# How To Stop Batch File From Opening New Windows?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm making a batch file that uses ffmpeg and ffprobe to encode a video. But every time I drag and drop my video onto the batch file, it opens a new command window.

How can I keep just one command window open, and have the batch file run in the same window every time, instead of opening a new one?

I run the batch file by drag and dropping my video files onto it.

Here is my batch code:

```
for /f %%i in ('D:\SOFTWARE\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=height -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%~1"') do set height=%%i

IF %height% GEQ 2160 (

echo "its above 2160!"
set bitrate=35000

) ELSE IF %height% GEQ 1440 (

echo "its above 1440!"
set bitrate=16000

) ELSE IF %height% GEQ 1080 (

echo "its above 1080!"
set bitrate=8000

) ELSE IF %height% GEQ 720 (

echo "its above 720!"
set bitrate=5000

) ELSE IF %height% GEQ 480 (

echo "its above 480!"
set bitrate=2500

) ELSE IF %height% GEQ 360 (

echo "its above 360!"
set bitrate=1000

) ELSE (

echo "its below 360!"
set bitrate=1000

)

D:\SOFTWARE\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -i "%~1" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -b:v %bitrate%k -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ac 2 "%~p1%~n1-out-h264.mp4"

cmd /k
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible using batch files.

Comment: Ok, the main thing I need is the ability to drag and drop files onto the batch file to enter them as parameters. Is there another way I can achieve this, maybe without batch files?

Comment: Not without writing some custom software.

Answer (score 0):

```
set callback=%1
tasklist /v | find /I /c "MyUniqueTitle" > nul
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" exit

title MyUniqueTitle

:main
for /f %%i in ('D:\SOFTWARE\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=height -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%callback%"') do set height=%%i

IF %height% GEQ 2160 (

echo "its above 2160!"
set bitrate=35000

) ELSE IF %height% GEQ 1440 (

echo "its above 1440!"
set bitrate=16000

) ELSE IF %height% GEQ 1080 (

echo "its above 1080!"
set bitrate=8000

) ELSE IF %height% GEQ 720 (

echo "its above 720!"
set bitrate=5000

) ELSE IF %height% GEQ 480 (

echo "its above 480!"
set bitrate=2500

) ELSE IF %height% GEQ 360 (

echo "its above 360!"
set bitrate=1000

) ELSE (

echo "its below 360!"
set bitrate=1000

)

D:\SOFTWARE\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -i "%callback%" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -b:v %bitrate%k -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ac 2 "%~p1%~n1-out-h264.mp4"

set callback=nul

:loop
if not %callback%==nul goto main
goto loop
```

The first line sets the variable callback to the first argument.

The second line checks if any instance with the title *MyUniqueTitle* is running. If so, the line 3 exits. If not, it goes to the next line and sets the title to *MyUniqueTitle* allowing the other instance you will start to exit because of the check in line 2.

At the end it goes into a loop which constantly controls if callback is set (by line 1 of another instance self-closing right after) and if so, it calls main, which executes that argument.

Hope this helps! If not, feel free to comment.